# Python Heroku - App not compatible with buildpack

Tags: python, git, heroku

I can't seem to figure out why my Heroku push keeps failing after hours and hours of research. The app works just fine in my terminal.

```
Counting objects: 12, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 5.80 KiB | 5.80 MiB/s, done.
Total 12 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to agile-brook-99462.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/agile-brook-99462.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/agile-brook-99462.git'
```

Things I have done:

- Set buildpack to heroku/python
- Set Python version to 2.7 with runtime.txt
- Added requirements.txt
- Added Procfile
- Tried `git push -f heroku master`
- Created a new app and re-tried all steps again

None of the above steps have remedied the situation. Any tips?

Comment: Have added and **committed** `runtime.txt` and `requirements.txt`?

Comment: No it wasn't committed. That solved it, my God! Thank you!

Comment: hey @phd i tried both and even ProcFile but still facing the issue. Python version 3.8.2